# How to keep sticky window from always getting focus in awesome wm

Tags: tags, focus, sticky, awesome-wm

In the awesome window manager the focused window of a tag regains its focus when switching back and forth between tags, i.e. by pressing `Mod+[Number]` or selecting them in the top bar.

Now when a window is marked as *sticky*, it will get the focus every time a different tag is selected. How can I prevent that?